# multiple NSFetchRequestController's in the same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is it a problem to have multiple NSFetchRequestControllers on the same view?  I have 4 tables in 1 view and need 4 controllers - I will have to use tags to differentiate between tables I guess - just curious as to a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with this. Assuming the data behind each of your tables aren't very closely related, you're going to end up with 4 separate data structures anyway (to cache the results of multiple fetches). One thing that might be useful is having a separate `dataSource` for each table, but a shared `delegate`. This way, you can handle the view logic in the shared delegate, for example pushing new view controllers when cells are selected. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use separate instances of controllers, and then setup the fetchResultsController based on which table you are populating, this should be fine.

I have 1 view controller that gets instantiated on two separate tabs to display the same data set in a different way. I just test which tab bar is selected on the NSFetchedResultsController method and apply the appropriate predicates accordingly:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSUInteger tab = [theDelegate.tabBarController selectedIndex];
switch (tab) {
    case kFeaturedTab: {
                // Setup sort desc & predicates
        }
    case kComingSoonTab: {
            // Setup alt. sort desc & predicates
    }
        ... // Do the fetch
}
```